# Terraform Datafusion deployment issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-data-fusion

i am hoping someone can assist me with this.
I am trying to spin up a datafusion instance in terraform/terragrunt and i am using the google_data_fusion_instance module. To my knowledge it is all configured correctly but when i push with cloudbuild it eventually fails in our step 2 with the following error:

```
Step #2: Error: Error creating Instance: googleapi: Error 400: Malformed name: 'projects/gc-t-prj-poc-0001-5473/locations/europe-west2/instances/'
Step #2: Details:
Step #2: [
Step #2:   {
Step #2:     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
Step #2:     "fieldViolations": [
Step #2:       {
Step #2:         "description": "URL path has empty component",
Step #2:         "field": "projects/gc-t-prj-poc-0001-5473/locations/europe-west2/instances/"
Step #2:       }
Step #2:     ]
Step #2:   }
Step #2: ]
```

I cannot seem to find anything on this error online at all so it's hard for me to diagnose my code when i have no idea which area seems to have an issue, or if im simply just missing some extra lines here and there.

Here is my terragrunt.hcl for it

```
terraform {
  source = "../../../../modules//data_fusion/"
}

# Include all settings from the root terragrunt.hcl file
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders("org.hcl")
}

dependency "project" {
  config_path = "../"

  # Configure mock outputs for the terraform commands that are returned when there are no outputs available (e.g the
  # module hasn't been applied yet.
  mock_outputs_allowed_terraform_commands = ["plan", "validate"]
  mock_outputs = {
    project_id = "gc-t-prj-poc-0001-5473"
  }
}

inputs = {
  project = "gc-t-prj-poc-0001-5473"
  name = "poc-df01"
  region = "europe-west2"
  type = "BASIC"
  enable_stackdriver_logging = false
  enable_stackdriver_monitoring = false
  #labels = var.labels
  private_instance = true
  network_config = {
    network_id = "projects/gc-a-prj-vpchost-0001-3312/global/networks/gc-t-vpc-0001"
    ip_allocation = "default"
  }
  version = "default"
  #namespace = "default"
  peer_name                           =  "gc-t-testfusionpeer-0001"  #gc-t-ip-datafusion-0001
  network_id                          = "projects/gc-a-prj-vpchost-0001-3312/global/networks/gc-t-vpc-0001"
  data_fusion_network                 = "projects/gc-a-prj-vpchost-0001-3312/global/networks/gc-t-datafusion-0001" 
  export_custom_routes                = true
  import_custom_routes                = true
```

Here is the main.tf of the module

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    cdap = {
      source = "GoogleCloudPlatform/cdap"
      # Pin to a specific version as 0.x releases are not guaranteed to be backwards compatible.
      version = "0.9.0"
    }
  }
}

 provider "cdap" {
  host  = "${module.datafusion_instance.wait_healthy_service_endpoint}/api/"
  token = data.google_client_config.current.access_token
}

data "google_client_config" "current" {}

resource "google_data_fusion_instance" "this" {
  provider = google-beta
  project = var.project
  name = var.data_fusion_instance
  description = "Data Fusion instance for ${var.region}"
  region = var.region
  type = "BASIC"
  enable_stackdriver_logging = false
  enable_stackdriver_monitoring = false
  labels = var.labels
  private_instance = true
  network_config {
    network = var.network_id
    ip_allocation = var.ip_allocation # format: "10.89.48.0/22"
  }
  version = var.data_fusion_version
 #dataproc_service_account = data.google_app_engine_default_service_account.default.email
}
#resource "cdap_namespace" "namespace" {
    #name = var.namespace
#}

resource "google_compute_network_peering" "peering" {

  name                                = var.peer_name
  network                             = var.network_id
  peer_network                        = var.data_fusion_network
  export_custom_routes                = var.export_custom_routes
  import_custom_routes                = var.import_custom_routes

}
```

It looks like part of it is deployed and the network peer is created
[image]

I am officially stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The error that is coming from the API makes it seem like the CDF instance name is missing. Instance creation requests need an instance name to be supplied when creating.

I see in your inputs that you list the CDF instance name as `name = "poc-df01"`.

However, in the resource definition, I see you try to use the `name = var.data_fusion_instance`, and it doesn't seem you have `data_fusion_instance` configured in the input variables.

Can you check if the variables are set correctly?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the kick in the right direction. I had indeed named a variable wrong in the inputs so i set that right and it successfully spins up now :) The only thing i cant get working is the peering. After it creates it gives the peered project id the name of the vpc - gc-a-prj-vpchost-0001-3312 instead of the project id from the datafusion instance cloud-datafusion-management-sa@**jba8c8977a73ce9f0-tp**.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: ```network_config = {
    network_id = "default" #"projects/gc-a-prj-vpchost-0001-3312/global/networks/gc-t-vpc-0001"
    ip_allocation = "default"
  }
```